# migrating Google Apps Marketplace item to OAuth v2.0

Tags: php, oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I have an app in the old Google Apps marketplace, and also the same App in Chrome Webstore. I tried migrating them to OAuth 2.0 by following steps described here https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2
When I get to Step 3 (Associate the two apps and their ownership), and I paste the Chrome Webstore item id as shown in the picture, I just simply get this error message - "Api console project id is missing for Chrome Webstore item id". The id seems to be correct, because if I enter something random, I get invalid id error. Seems that something is missing and not described in the page above. How can I make this work to start using OAuth 2.0?

Comment: Might be useful to ask someone on their G+ community page - https://plus.google.com/communities/116649587096405255956